# What analysis should I run if I have 40 predictors and I want to know which are related to the dependent variable?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, feature-selection

I have forty candidate predictors. They are no colinear. I want to know which ones are related to the DV. Prediction isn't important to me. I want to do this in an exploratory and data-driven way.

What's my best option? I've looked at: multiple regression, stepwise regression (AIC,BIC), best subsets regression, and Adaptive LASSO.

Is one of those better than the others? And if not, what is a better option?

Comment: Check out articles by [Chernozhukov](https://arxiv.org/search/?query=chernozhukov&searchtype=all&source=header) and [various other](https://arxiv.org/search/?query=double+post+lasso&searchtype=all&abstracts=show&order=-announced_date_first&size=50), for high dimensional inference/treatment problems. Double post-lasso may be a good start, check out ``hdm`` package of R.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [battery of problems with stepwise regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/176202), which also includes best subset regression. Multiple regression is fine if $n\gg p$, otherwise you may be better off using regularization.

Namely, a regularized model (like the LASSO you mentioned), restricts the total size of the parameter estimates. Perhaps somewhat surprisingly, [introducing this bias can yield better estimates](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/452548/176202), especially for small $\frac{n}{p}$ ratios.